# How to do Amazon EMR cleanup steps on termination

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I am using boto3 API to create an Amazon EMR cluster.

Using bootstrap actions, I am able to run script when the server is started. Can a similar action be done when I terminate the cluster, so that I am able to do actions like backup the metastore and data to S3 before the cluster is terminated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to setup bootstrap actions to run on EMR after core services are installed (Spark etc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211309/is-there-a-way-to-setup-bootstrap-actions-to-run-on-emr-after-core-services-are)

Comment: You can add steps to do something with the shell script.

Comment: What is triggering the termination of the cluster? Could the thing that is triggering the termination run a step first, wait for it to complete, then perform the termination?

Comment: @Lamanus it is not a duplicate of your question, in your case the steps have to be performed by after server is starting, however in my case i want to do steps just before the cluster is terminated, sort of like bootstrapping actions but for termination.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks i'll give your approach a try.

Comment: You can do the termination by step with some job. I think this way is the only thing.